# Priority queue of doubles using vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, priority-queue

I need to write the code for a priority queue using an STL vector

I have been assigned the task of implementing a priority queue of doubles using vector
previously I had implemented a queue using list, this was very straight forward as list provided me with all the functions I needed.
Unless I'm missing something that's not the case with a priority queue?

The reference for a Priority Queue on cplusplus.com notes: One call to push_back on the underlying container(vector) and one call to push_heap (I assume algorithm), I'm not sure how to implement push_heap and pop_heap or whether I need to at all.

The assignment specifically asks for vector

I'm looking for a good implementation/explanation of this.

This is mo code so far:

.cpp

```
#include"PriorityQueue.h"
#include <algorithm>

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(){

}
void PriorityQueue::push(double val){
    s.push_back(val);

}
void PriorityQueue::pop(){


}
double PriorityQueue::front() const{
    return s.front();
}
double PriorityQueue::back() const{
    return s.back();
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUE_H
#define PRIORITYQUEUE_H
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
class PriorityQueue{
public:
    PriorityQueue();
    void push(double val);
    void pop();
    double front() const;
    double back() const;
private:
    vector<double> s;
};
#endif // !PRIORITYQUEUE_H
```

If I need to write the code to keep track of the top and bottom indexes, I may be missing essential functions, I'm just kinda stuck and don't have the time to waste trying loads of different solutions.

Comment: I can't quite see a question here. If it's "why can't I use `list`?", then you need random access to rearrange the elements into a [heap structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). `vector` is a fine choice for that.

Comment: I need to write the code for a priority queue using an STL vector

Comment: @Johntk if you can use algorithm and you can use vector, why can't you use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @Johntk: Yes, so you said. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: Its just for learning purposes so we understand what the underlying code is doing.
Also I haven't used algorithm  yet, i'm just aware of it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, for my pop function, is there a function I can call in vector to achieve the functionality of a priority queue, or do I need to write the code myself?

Comment: @Johntk: No, `vector` doesn't do anything like that. There are algorithms like `push_heap`, which the standard `priority_queue` adapter uses. Although the point of the exercise might be to make your own heap structure; if you can use the algorithms from the standard library, you might as well use `priority_queue` itself.

Comment: I was afraid of that, so I will have to write the code myself, or if I was able to use deque rather than vector(deque is a type of vector?), I believe it has the function I need?

Comment: No, `deque` does not have any functions for creating heaps or sorting its members either. The functions for manipulating heaps are in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: @Johntk: No, `deque` has functions for manipulating both ends of its sequence, but also isn't a priority queue. The only standard priority queue is the `priority_queue` adapter itself. You can use that (in which case the exercise is pointless); use the same standard algorithms that it uses (in which case the exercise is very straightforward), or implement your own heap operations (which is probably the point of the exercise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use a `std::vector` and add items to it using `push_back` combined with `std::push_heap` from the `algorithm` header.

Comment: N.B. `algorithm` not `algorithms`, and `push_heap` can't add anything to a `vector`, what it can do is re-order the existing elements in a range (such as a vector's elements) so they form a heap. You need to use `push_back` to add to the vector, then use `push_heap` to rebuild the heap

Comment: @JonathanWakely you're right, I've corrected the answer.